# Not getting LastModifiedBy.Name and CreatedBy.Name from query

Tags: apex, soql

Does anyone know why this query does not show the `LastModifiedByName` and `CreatedBy.Name` even though I am explicitly asking for it?

```
List <Report> result = [SELECT Name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Name FROM Report];
System.debug(result);
```

In the output (running execute anonymous window), I see everything except for these items. But if I were to run it in the query editor in the developer console, it works fine. Am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using `system.debug();`, the data on related records is not shown. In other words, if you have *any* dot/period/full-stop to access the field in your query, you won't see it. That's just the way it works.

If you iterate through each result of the query and specifically `system.debug(myReportRec.LastModifiedBy.Name);`, you would see it.

If you serialize the results as JSON, and debug them, you'd see the related records as well.

Comment: How would I go about serializing the results as JSON?

Comment: @apexdev using `JSON.serialize()`

Comment: I'm doing it like this: ```List <Report> result = [SELECT Name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Id, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Name FROM Report];
for (Report stuff : result) {
    system.debug(JSON.serialize(stuff));
}``` But I'm still not seeing the names, only the ID's.